# App script appendRow with RichTextValue variable

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

trying to use app script appendrow with multilple values one of them is a RichTextValue variable.

```
    var richValue = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
   .setText('link')
   .setLinkUrl('www.somesite.com')
   .build();

sheet.appendRow([varX,varY,varZ,richValue ]);
```

problem is using appendRow with a richValue dont add the properties of the richValue.

the only documented way I found to add a RichTextValue to the sheet is via setRichTextValue/s

I know its possible to get the same result with setRichTextValue/s but I prefer if there is a work around to use appendRow with RichTextValue variables.

Comment: Now, I noticed your comment of `it allow me to also choose the index location of the richValue in the appended row.`. In this case, I think that my answer was not suitable for your question. I had thought that you wanted to put the richText to the column "D". This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. So, I have to delete my answer. Because I don't want to confuse other users. I would like to study more.

Comment: Although it wasn't the best solution for my problem it is still a good solution that actually made me familiar with the offset method which I'm grateful for, so tyvm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the [appendRows_()](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/159426/269219) utility function, like this:

```
const richValue = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
  .setText('link')
  .setLinkUrl('www.somesite.com')
  .build();
appendRows_(sheet, [varX, varY, varZ, richValue]);
```

Comment: tyvm although both Tanaike answer and yours was very helpful i found this solution best suits this current script because it allow me to also choose the index location of the richValue in the appended row.